# How to capitalize first letter of a string in VBScript

Tags: vbscript

I read a really helpful post here [How do I make the first letter of a string uppercase in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1026069/capitalize-the-first-letter-of-string-in-javascript) and I was curious of a good solution using VBScript.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
>> s = "first word of string"
>> WScript.Echo UCase(Left(s, 1)) &  Mid(s, 2)
>>
First word of string
```

Comment: This is what I came up with.

Answer (score 3):

```
str = "mY nAME iS sACHIN"

arrStr = split(str," ")

For i=0 to ubound(arrStr)

 word = lcase(trim(arrStr(i)))
 word = replace(word,mid(word,1,1),chr(asc(mid(word,1,1))-32),1,1)
 str1 = str1 & word & " "
next

msgbox trim(str1)
```

Output: My Name Is Sachin

Comment: (1) The task is to 'capitalize the first word of a string", not every word of the string, and no LCase was asked for (2) (Unrestricticed) Replace will capitalize **all** occurrences of the first letter (3) Concatenation will add a spurious trailing blank.

Comment: Problem (2) is easy to solve. Just use `Replace(string,find,replacewith,1,1)` instead of `Replace(string,find,replacewith)`. Reference: http://www.w3schools.com/asp/func_replace.asp

Comment: I'm not going to upvote this answer just because it's not the answer to the question. But I was searching how I could capitalize the first letter of every word, I came up to this page and that piece of code worked for me. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
str = "mY nAME iS sACHIN"
arrStr = split(str," ")
For i=0 to ubound(arrStr)
 word = lcase(trim(arrStr(i))) 
 word = replace(word,mid(word,1,1),ucase(mid(word,1,1)),1,1)                  
 str1 = str1 & word & " "
 next
msgbox trim(str1)
```